# What else should I consider to benchmark this code

Tags: c++, benchmarking

I've written a code to convert large number of letters from small to capital format via two approaches. The first approach, I utilize bit-wise operation and the second one is using switch statement. My ultimate goal is to use this example as a reference for understanding the benchmark. What are the parameters should I consider in my code to judge whether using bitwise operation is better than using switch. So far, I'm using the elapsed time as an indicator for better performance. In my example,

```
Lower2UpperBitwise:
      elapsed time: 0.655201s

 Lower2UpperSwitch:
      elapsed time: 3.30221s
```

I'm running the code in Windows with cygwin and this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>


void Lower2UpperBitwise(std::string& str)
{
    int mask = 0xDF;
    long i(0); 

    while ( i != (long)str.size() )
        str[i++] &= mask;

}

void Lower2UpperSwitch(std::string& str)
{
    for ( long i(0); i < (long)str.size(); ++i ){
        switch(str[i]){
            case 'a': str[i] = 'A'; break;  
            case 'b': str[i] = 'B'; break;
            case 'c': str[i] = 'C'; break;  
            case 'd': str[i] = 'D'; break;
            case 'e': str[i] = 'E'; break;  
            case 'f': str[i] = 'F'; break;
            case 'g': str[i] = 'G'; break;  
            case 'h': str[i] = 'H'; break;
            case 'i': str[i] = 'I'; break;  
            case 'j': str[i] = 'J'; break;
            case 'k': str[i] = 'K'; break;  
            case 'l': str[i] = 'L'; break;
            case 'm': str[i] = 'M'; break;  
            case 'n': str[i] = 'N'; break;
            case 'o': str[i] = 'O'; break;  
            case 'p': str[i] = 'P'; break;
            case 'q': str[i] = 'Q'; break;  
            case 'r': str[i] = 'R'; break;
            case 's': str[i] = 'S'; break;  
            case 't': str[i] = 'T'; break;
            case 'u': str[i] = 'U'; break;
            case 'v': str[i] = 'V'; break;  
            case 'w': str[i] = 'W'; break;
            case 'x': str[i] = 'X'; break;  
            case 'y': str[i] = 'Y'; break;
            case 'z': str[i] = 'Z'; break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}



int main()
{
    //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    /* Setting up the random generator */
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> di(97,122);  // (97 : a)  (122 : z)


    // string size: 200,000,000
    const long SIZE( 200000000 );
    std::string str;

    //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    /* Fill string with random small letters (a-z) */
    for (long i(0); i < SIZE; ++i) {
        int temp = di(mt);
        str.push_back( static_cast<char>(temp) );
    }
    /* =========================================== */


    std::string temp;
    temp = str;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds;

    // Using bitwise operation )##################################
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();  // <-- Start 
    Lower2UpperBitwise(temp);                  // <-- Run 
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();    // <-- End

    elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    std::cout << "\nLower2UpperBitwise:\n";
    std::cout << "      elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";


    // Using Switch operation )#####################################
    temp = str;

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now(); // <-- Start 
    Lower2UpperSwitch(temp);                  // <-- Run 
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();   // <-- End

    elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    std::cout << "\n Lower2UpperSwitch:\n";
    std::cout << "      elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";


    return 0;
}
```

and this is the Makefile.

```
CXX      = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 
TARGET   = test

.PHONY: all 
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): main.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp -o $(TARGET) 

.PHONY: clean   
clean:
    rm *.o $(TARGET)
```

Comment: A switch isn't necessary. Just subtract the ascii difference.

Comment: You should use std::chrono::high_resolution_clock for timer

Comment: Also, you may want to test it against a sorted array to test branch prediction effectiveness.

Comment: [Benchmarking code talk by Chandler Carruth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk)

Comment: Try `str[i] = toupper(str[i]);` This should eliminate your switch statement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Mysticial, you're missing the point. Using switch is only to compare it with the bitwise. I know that the switch is not efficient.